# Merge 2 Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, merge

How to merge 2 lists in Java?

I want to retrieve data rows from database and then make some edits to this  data: add, delete, edit records. But when I add new record and reload my page, all records in database are duplicated!?

What's wrong? Where's my flaw?

Thanks in advance!

My lists:

```
private List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>(getAllUsers());

public List<Order> getOrderList() {
    return orderList;
}

public List<Order> getAllUsers() {
    try {
        orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection connection = databaseConnection.getConnection();
        SQL = "SELECT * FROM Registration";
        prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        resultSet = prepStatement.executeQuery();
        boolean foundResult = false;
        while (resultSet.next() == true) {
            orders = new Order(id, orderNo, productName, price, qty);
            orders.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            orders.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
            orders.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
            orders.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
            orders.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
            orderList.add(orders);
            foundResult = true;
        }
        resultSet.close();
        prepStatement.close();
        if (foundResult) {

            return orderList;

        } else {
            return null; // no entries found.
        }
    } catch (Exception eX) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Error in getMeineList()--> " + eX.getMessage());
        return (null);
    }

}

public String addNew() {
    orders = new Order();
    orders.setEditable(true);
    orderList.add(orders);
    return "";
}

public String edit(Order ord) {
    ord.setEditable(true);
    return null;
}

public void insert() {
    // int q= 0;
    System.out.println("Inserting...!");
    try {
        connection = databaseConnection.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        SQL = "INSERT INTO Registration (orderNo,productName,price,qty) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        prepStatement.setString(1, orderNo);
        prepStatement.setString(2, productName);
        prepStatement.setBigDecimal(3, price);
        prepStatement.setInt(4, qty);
        prepStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("User added Successfully!");
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("New User added!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("adminForm: saveButton", message);
        statement.close();
        prepStatement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException SQLex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        SQLex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception IOex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        IOex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably that the only SQL code you ever run is an `INSERT` query : you never `UPDATE` your data. I don't think you gave us enough code to be sure, where is the part where you "add, delete, edit records" ?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at persistency frameworks like Hibernate, but it would be best to first have a basic understanding of SQL